# Distributing new security certificates from SB2011 to clients

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I have a local network with a SBS2011 and Exchange 2010 server with a bunch of mixed Windows clients.

The exchange certificates expired, so I reissued them; they’re valid for the next 5 years. However, the clients still complain after starting Outlook that the certificates expired, and installing new ones doesn’t get results. I tried to enable the Client-Certificate Service in group policies and refresh them, but that didn’t work.

I have almost no experience with this, so I’ve probably missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have missed the obvious - buy a certificate. 
You can get a suitable certificate for less than $50 if you look around and it will save all of the hassle of trying to get various clients to trust a new self signed certificate. Saves a lot of time as well.